# Correct way to create nswindow, using Swift and Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

Normally I would use this method to open a new window with a window controller

```
@class WindowTestController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSWindow        *window;
    WindowTestController     *windowController;
}
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    @property (strong) WindowTestController *windowController;

    - (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

And then

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "WindowTestController"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize window;
    @synthesize windowController;

- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (windowController == nil) 
           testWindow = [[WindowTestController alloc] init];
           [windowController showWindow:nil];
    }

@end
```

In trying to do a similar thing in swift I've got the following

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var testWindow: NSWindowController = WindowTestController(windowNibName: "Window")

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {

        testWindow.showWindow(nil)
}

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

In this situation as I have to set a default value for the testWindow property I'm creating an instance of WindowTestController before I need it. i.e. I don't need to do the

```
if (windowController == nil)
```

Is this correct or is there another method that allocates the resource when required, or am I worrying about nothing?

Doing

```
if (windowController == nil) 
       testWindow = WindowTestController(windowNibName: "Window")
}
```

Without the AppDelegate property Results in the window immediately disappearing (i.e deallocated I think).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might a be a job for `lazy`

```
class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate {
    lazy var windowController = WindowTestController(windowNibName: "Window")

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
        windowController.showWindow(sender)
    }
}
```

`self.windowController` will be neither allocated nor nil until you attempt to call it, at which time it will be inited.  But not until that time.

Comment: @iluvcapra how do you know this? where can i find tutorials showing this to me?

Comment: I dunno, I just came up with it :)

Since I posted this, Apple has removed the "@" sign from the lazy keyword.