# Closing an NSWindow via AppDelegate

Tags: macos, swift, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am using the Parse framework. When I login my user I run a method on my AppDelegate like so:

```
        if user != nil {
            let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.authSuccess()
        } else {
```

My AppDelegate has:

```
let mainWindowController = MainWindowController(windowNibName: "MainWindow")
var authWindowController = AuthWindowController(windowNibName: "AuthWindow")

func authSuccess() {
    self.authWindowController.window?.close()
    self.mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
}
```

The Main window is opening, but the auth window is not closing. I have tried  `close:`, `orderOut:`, `performClose:` without any luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What debug says? Are you sure that you have only one instance of authWindowController (check how many times awakeFromNib is called).

Comment: Nothing in debug but there are two awakeFromNibs!

Comment: Following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224886/correct-way-to-create-nswindow-using-swift-and-cocoa, even when I put the var as `lazy` it is still being initialised twice...

Comment: The first is from XIB and the second is from your code. Either create IBOutlet from XIB and stay away from creation of your second instance or put your auth window in it's own XIB and control creation. If you have your window together with the main menu XIB -> your issue.

Comment: So I've figured out the problem. My NSWindowController instance does not have a valid NSWindow instance, so when I was closing it it had nothing to close.

So I've set the window as a custom property of my window controller and am closing that instead.

Comment: I also fixed it so I only have one WindowController instance.